# How to quickly enrage a wave many times

Tags: gemcraft-chasing-shadows

In Gemcraft there's a huge advantage to enrage waves with the cheapest possible gem. But this requires a lot of work because you'll need to do it many times.

There's softare to combine gems and maybe this could also be used to enrage waves.

But I only want to enrage the waves, is there a way to do that quickly without extra software?

Like you can fill up your entire inventory space with a gem level in one click.
I'm looking for a combination that bombs the entire gem inventory into one target (wave).

Edit:
I've seen one Youtuber [do this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ruqrGuFcHdg&t=342s) in a video, it includes the mouse wheel to set a stack on the gem bomb spell, but I've been unable to reproduce this myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press spell button -> hold shift -> your first gem will be highlighted as the gem to use in bombing -> with each click one of the selected gem will be applied as enrage to the wave for each configured amount.
Additionaly I've found you should scroll mouse wheel up on the Gem bomb spell. That increases the number of gems of the selected level that will be bombed.
With a good mana gem enhanced in a trap I can usually get a good kill gem enhanced in a trap and I'm able to scroll all the way up to 247 for max wave boost from the first level onwards. With giants a gem bomb will boost 4x slower, but with them I rarely go for full boost. Usually I can only handle 2-3 times the scrolled stack, depending on the bonuses they have.